# flask application starts without giving debugging pin, also no request info displayed

Tags: python-2.7, flask, werkzeug

I'm truly uncertain how I got into this mode, but when I start my flask application on the development system, I see

`2016-11-17 17:20:36,717 WARNING: * Debugger is active!`

but there is no display of the debugging PIN and I don't see the requests which come in to the server.

When this started happening I poked around a bit to try to see what change I made to cause this, but was too embroiled in making the application work to follow up at the time. Of course any history is long gone.

Do you have any suggestions on how to debug this?

In case it matters, I'm running on windows.

I dumped app.config using

```
        configkeys = app.config.keys()
        configkeys.sort()
        appconfig = []
        for key in configkeys:
            value = app.config[key]
            if not owner_permission.can():
                if key in ['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI','SECRET_KEY']:
                    value = '<obscured>'
            appconfig.append({'label':key, 'value':value})
        sysvars.append(['app.config',appconfig])
```

(later display of sysvars in html template) and see the following. I also tried setting `debug=True` in the `run()` invocation but no effect.

`APPLICATION_ROOT /
DEBUG   True
EXPLAIN_TEMPLATE_LOADING    False
JSONIFY_MIMETYPE    application/json
JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR True
JSON_AS_ASCII   True
JSON_SORT_KEYS  True
LOGGER_HANDLER_POLICY   always
LOGGER_NAME rrwebapp
LOGGING_LEVEL_FILE  20
LOGGING_LEVEL_MAIL  40
LOGGING_MAIL_HANDLER    <logging.handlers.SMTPHandler object at 0x03806630>
LOGGING_PATH    C:\\Users\\Lou\\Documents\\Lou's Software\\projects\\rrwebapp\\rrwebapp.log
MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH  None
MINIMIZE_CDN_JAVASCRIPT False
PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME  31 days, 0:00:00
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME    http
PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION   None
PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS    None
SECRET_KEY  flask development key
SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT   12:00:00
SERVER_NAME None
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME session
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH None
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   False
SESSION_REFRESH_EACH_REQUEST    True
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS    None
SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN   False
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI mysql://rrwebuser:xxxxxxxxx@127.0.0.1/testnewracedb
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO False
SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW None
SQLALCHEMY_NATIVE_UNICODE   None
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE None
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE    None
SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT None
SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES   None
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS  False
TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD   None
TESTING False
TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS False
TRAP_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS    False
USE_X_SENDFILE  False`

12/27/16 adding requirements.txt

```
alembic==0.8.8
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
appdirs==1.4.0
attrdict==2.0.0
billiard==3.3.0.23
blinker==1.4
celery==3.1.23
click==6.6
docutils==0.11
docx==0.2.4
ecdsa==0.13
ez-setup==0.9
Fabric==1.11.1
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-Uploads==0.2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
flup==1.0.2
googlemaps==2.4.4
gpxpy==1.1.2
haversine==0.4.5
httplib2==0.9.2
ipython==1.1.0
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
kombu==3.0.35
loutilities==0.11.0
lxml==3.6.0
Mako==1.0.4
MarkupSafe==0.23
mysql-python==1.2.5
oauthlib==2.0.0
paramiko==1.17.0
Pillow==3.2.0
pycrypto==2.6.1
pyreadline==2.0
python-editor==1.0.1
pytz==2013.9
requests==2.10.0
requests-oauthlib==0.7.0
running==1.4.0
six==1.10.0
SQLAlchemy==1.0.15
sqlalchemy-datatables===0.4.1lk3
tzlocal==1.0
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Werkzeug==0.11.11
WTForms==2.1
xlrd==0.9.2
xlwt==0.7.5
```

Comment: can you add your *requirements.txt* or output of `pip freeze`? depending on which version of flask you are using, you might not see the debugger pin. a few releases ago that wasn't a thing.

Comment: done. I was seeing debugger pin and I'm not sure what change I made but it disappeared, I think along with the request outputs

Comment: see here (just in case you missed something): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309889. and if the config values you listed are environment variables, try: `FLASK_DEBUG=true` instead.

Comment: Pretty sure I looked at that question, and the values I list are a dump of app.config so I'm sure the debug flag is set. Also note I see "2016-11-17 17:20:36,717 WARNING: * Debugger is active!" but no pin.

Comment: I also tried poking through the flask code but was unable to find where the PIN is set and displayed to try to figure out what conditions need to be met. If you know the code maybe you have some guidance?

Comment: Hmm, not sure why I didn't find this before, but tried poking around werkzeug , searched for 'debugger is active' and see message, but don't quite understand why I don't see additional message after that. Looks like either I should see DEBUGGER UNSECURED or debugger pin code. Ref werkzeug.__init__ line 253 [version 0.11.11]

Comment: how are you setting your config? environment variables, config file? the pin stuff is in werkzeug starting a 0.11 which you have, so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131628/discussion-between-lou-k-and-wgwz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem turned out to be that log level was set incorrectly when werkzeug started, causing info messages to be obscured. Needs further debug but this is clearly a problem with my app initialization.

Adding following code to my initialization takes care of the problem.

```
# patch werkzeug logging -- not sure why this is being bypassed in werkzeug._internal._log
werkzeug_logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
werkzeug_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

UPDATE 5/8/2019:
Per Jorge Mendes comment, WERKZEUG_DEBUG_PIN can be used to set a specific pin as alternate fix

Comment: Have the same problem didn't managed to get the pin to used `WERKZEUG_DEBUG_PIN`  to set a specific pin number