# Python Flask Heroku Log Error

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run a Python Flask heroku app, and am getting this error when visiting the web page.

I have absolutely no idea why

```
 2018-04-23T13:21:20.430586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=avian-hero.herokuapp.com request_id=53d7abca-826a-40e3-a0db-68d6bdc9f3a6 fwd="80.1.113.164" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-04-23T13:21:20.584930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=avian-hero.herokuapp.com request_id=860212c4-203c-4e9e-87f9-2df263203ac9 fwd="80.1.113.164" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am deploying with Gunicorn if that helps.

Comment: This means your flask app has errored. You can try to run it locally for instance to see what's the matter.

Comment: This means your flask app has errored. You can try to run it locally for instance to see what's the matter.

Comment: Ah but it works locally, that's why I'm so confused

Comment: Did you try some of these things? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309889/how-to-debug-a-flask-app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950674/debugging-a-flask-app-running-in-gunicorn