# Flask code doesn't update when i upload it

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask, gunicorn

i just deployed my first flask app and it was amazing, but i'm facing a problem i can't understand.

when i was developing my app (Window) i used set FLASK_ENV=development to see the changes in my app without restarting the flask server, when i uploaded the app to my vps worked great, but, when i tried to upload a new changes the app doesn't update.

Can someone explain me why my flask app code doesn't update when i upload it to my vps?

i'm using **Gunicorn** and i have already put the debug to true

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when i visit my site i can't see the changes made just the first code i uploaded when i set the server.

What should i do to update my code once uploaded?

Comment: restart server. Gunicorn doesn't use code in `if __name__ == '__main__'` but it imports `app` and  runs `app.run()` on its own.

Comment: I've had issues where my IDE (visual studio) wasn't updating my code changes. My fix was to first restart the server and if that didn't work restart my IDE running the code.

Comment: to set debug you would have to use rather `app.debug = True` directly after `app = Flask(...)` or eventually set `FLASK_DEBUG=1` in environment - [How to debug a Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309889/how-to-debug-a-flask-app)

Comment: [Debugging a Flask app running in Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950674/debugging-a-flask-app-running-in-gunicorn)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone is interested in this problem, i've solved it by using:

```
sudo supervisorctl stop app_name
sudo supervisorctl start app_name
```

(yeah! i forgot to mention i'm using supervisor to handle the autostart.)