# How do I fix this 404 error for a button added with "url_for"

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a basic flask todo list web application, with main `app.py` and 4 html pages, `add.html`, `edit.html`, `home.html`, `todos.html`.

Everything works perfectly fine, except when "add todo" button is clicked on the main page, I have this error 404:

[image]

Here's my **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todos.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='Incomplete')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_todo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        description = request.form['description']
        new_todo = Todo(description=description)
        db.session.add(new_todo)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('todos'))

    return render_template('add.html')

@app.route('/todos')
def todos():
    todos = Todo.query.order_by(Todo.status, Todo.id).all()
    return render_template('todos.html', todos=todos)

@app.route('/todos/mark_complete/<int:todo_id>')
def mark_complete(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.get_or_404(todo_id)
    todo.status = 'Completed'
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('todos'))

@app.route('/todos/mark_incomplete/<int:todo_id>')
def mark_incomplete(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.get_or_404(todo_id)
    todo.status = 'Incomplete'
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('todos'))

@app.route('/todos/edit/<int:todo_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.get_or_404(todo_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        todo.description = request.form['description']
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('todos'))

    return render_template('edit.html', todo=todo)

@app.route('/todos/delete/<int:todo_id>')
def delete(todo_id):
    todo = Todo.query.get_or_404(todo_id)
    db.session.delete(todo)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('todos'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

And here's my **add.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Add ToDo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Add ToDo</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('add_todo') }}">
    <label for="description">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [todo-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/todo): "... Please do not use this for questions about creating todo list applications."

Comment: What is the URL that the button tries to navigate to?

Comment: @dsakhuria, your code is working properly for me. I did not modify your code and it is adding new todo. I have added another HTML template for `todos` and it is showing the newly added todo. One suggestion might be to use debug mode in flask : https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#debug-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problems fixed, issue was that the button itself was reffering to wrong directory, instead of path/add, it was going to path/todo/add which wasnt really existing(thats the reason of why error 404 raised), ty anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing your code, it appears that the code itself is correct and should work as expected. Therefore the issue is not related to the code itself.

Here's a working version using your code -

1. https://replit.com/@Om-Mishra/AdmiredPrestigiousArguments
2. https://admiredprestigiousarguments.om-mishra.repl.co/add

If you're encountering a 404 error when clicking the "add todo" button, it could be due to a misconfiguration in your Flask application or an issue with the server setup. To troubleshoot that try running the app in debug mode - [How to debug a Flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309889/how-to-debug-a-flask-app)